# Give userid and guid in code behind to signalr server

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I want to add a signalr chat application to my existing website. You can login my site to come in the member area. In the member area will be a chat function.

On every page in the member area I read out a encrypted cookie with the userid and a guid. When I make a call to the database I check if there userid and guid belong the each other.

Now when I start the chat application I send the userid and guid to the signalr server with javascript. That is working but when I view the source code I see the userid and guid.

Is it possible to add the userid and guid in code behind just before I start the chat connection, so that I don't have to pass them in javascript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the values in the cookie are encrypted, and you're injecting the decrypted values in the javascript before it's sent to the client.

You could read the cookie with javascript on the client, this way the values aren't visible in the source and you can send the encrypted values. You can read [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) how.

If the values in the cookie aren't encrypted, it doesn't make a lot of sense to me, because the values in the cookie can be seen by the user just as easy as the javascript source.